# Meteor.js, update view value based on template data, but not the record itself (ie. just view model)

Tags: javascript, meteor, viewmodel

I'm trying to get my meteor template to show an update value when I change the template data within any JS function, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. 
Here is the code:

```
Template.editorder.rendered = function() {
  var self = this;

  //reference this.data later on
  Template.editorder.data = this.data;

  //Initialize the date pickers
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        selectedDate: new Date(),
        onDateChanged: function(date) {
            var d = new Date(date);
            //TRYING TO UPDATE THE "VIEW MODEL" HERE
            self.data.dateCreated = Template.editorder.data.dateCreated = date;
        }
    });
};
```

In my view I simply have:

```
<template name="editorder">
 ...
 Date created: {{dateCreated}}
 ...
</template>
```

This doesn't work at all. self.data.dateCreated or Template.editorder.data.dateCreated aren't reflected in the view. I think the only way to get the update to show is to update the published data object itself, but I don't want to send the changed to the database yet.

I guess maybe the way to do this is to use a template helper, but in my testing I can't seem to get that to work either. I've tried setting up a Template.editorder.viewmodel = function() { } method which returns a global object scope, which I assigned to be 'this.data' within the Template.editorder.rendered() function, but updating that viewmodel isn't updating the view either.

Is there any way to do this?
Thanks for any help.

**Solution:** You have to use the Session.set() within your custom method, and Session.get() to retrieve that variable within a template helper method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is using Session.

When the date changes you'd call Session.set('dateCreated', newDate).

The template helper for dateCreated would simply return Session.get('dateCreated').

Comment: Great! Thank you for the solution. Personally, I wish there was a better way to handle this scenario. Relying on "session" variables seems liek a roundabout way. Maybe meteor will introduce a more integrated solution down the road.

Answer (score 1):

To change value reactively you need to have a helper which returns a reactive variable.

```
Template.editorder.helpers({
  dateCreated: function() {
    return Session.get('dateCreated');
  }
});
```

And the onDateChanged function will look like this:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
  onDateChanged: function(date) {
    Session.set('dateCreated', date);
  }
});
```